# Is there a lower bound for the inner product of two complex vectors with unit magnitude entries?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, inner-products

From Cauchy–Schwarz inequality, we know that $\left|\langle \mathbf {u} ,\mathbf {v} \rangle \right|^{2}\leq \langle \mathbf {u} ,\mathbf {u} \rangle \cdot \langle \mathbf {v} ,\mathbf {v} \rangle $, where $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{C}^N$ and $\langle \cdot \rangle$ denotes the inner product operation. I am wondering whether there are conditions which lead to a lower bound for two complex vectors, when each entry for both vectors has unit magnitude as $\left| \mathbf{u}(i)\right|,\left| \mathbf{v}(i)\right| = 1, i=1\ldots N$.

Comment: For real vectors, consider $u = [1,1]^{\top}$ and $v = [1, -1]^{\top}$. Clearly $\langle u,v \rangle = 0$. So I don't think one can hope for a better lower bound unless additional conditions are imposed on $u$ and $v$.

Comment: Yes, I will try to find out whether the other addtional conditions are gonna give me a more special lower bound.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of "reverse cauchy-schwarz" inequalities but obviously you'll need some assumptions since the two vectors can be orthogonal in which case the inner product is zero. See [this paper](https://rgmia.org/papers/v7n1/ReverseSchwarz.pdf), for example.

One particular case is the Diaz-Metcalfe inequality. If $a_k,b_k$ are $n$ complex numbers with $a_k\neq 0,$ for all $k=1,\ldots,n$ and
$$
m\leq \mathrm{Re} \frac{b_k}{a_k}+\mathrm{Im} \frac{b_k}{a_k} \leq M,
$$
as well as
$$
m\leq \mathrm{Re} \frac{b_k}{a_k}-\mathrm{Im} \frac{b_k}{a_k} \leq M,
$$
for $k=1,\ldots, n,$ then we have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n |b_k|^2+mM \sum_{k=1}^n |a_k|^2\leq
$$
$$
\leq
(m+M)\mathrm{Re} \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \overline{b_k}
\leq |m+M| \left|\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \overline{b_k}\right|
$$

Comment: Really thanks for the answer, I will read the paper to see whether I can find some property from my particular case!